# MKS/PTC Integrity CLI commands for electronic signatures

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, popen, mks-integrity

I am trying to edit an issue in PTC integrity using the CLI command:

```
im editissue --hostname= --password=<password> --field= ......
```

On execution of the command, it asks for Electronic signature credentials which are needed to complete the command execution. It returns the below statement

> ```
> Please sign this document to note your approval.
> Signing User:
> Signing Password:
> Signature Comment:
> ```

Can I pass the electronic signature credentials along with the first command ?
OR can I pass additional arguments at runtime

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MKS/`im` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

additional arguments needs to be added at runtime for each command:

```
im editissue --hostname=XXXX --port=XXXX **--user=XXXX --password="XXXX"** --field="fieldName=fieldValue" -- ItemID
```